# Mac Application Adding Hidden Version & Build Number to Text Pasted From App - Does Not Show in Clipboard?

Tags: mac

I am using GargeSale 7.0.16, which is a eBay listing tool.

There are two editable modes to each listing.

Editor (edit HTML directly)

Preview (styled text edit - automaticcaly converts to HTML as typed)

In the styled text mode I copy all the text to the clipboard.

I look at the clipboard and it looks fine.

I paste the text into another app and this has been added below the text I copied on a new line:

_gsrx_vers_841 (GS 7.0.16 (841))

Why on earth is this app be inserting unwanted hidden text about its version and build number on the clipboard?

I checked my html master templates and there is no code that would insert this.

I don't get it.  Is there any way to disable this?